# Bash intructions to execute p1|p2

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Can some one help me answer this question:
What is  the sequence of instructions (the system calls) that allow the bash process to interpret and execute the command
p1 | p2 , p1 and p2 are two executable files.

Comment: Next time try google: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run, the "|" is called a pipe!

Comment: I know exactly what | means and how to use pipes in linux.

Comment: My question is about the instructions executed by bash to execute the command

Comment: The system calls executed for example.

Comment: using strace to check the system calls involved I get alot of traces and I can't understand much

Comment: More or less the sequence is: `dup()`, `dup2()`, `fork()`, `exec()`,`dup2()`. Some of those syscalls may be run more than once.

Comment: Ah, sorry... well the wording might a little bit of in your question? (If you edit it, I can remove my down vote). So you're asking... just this from a theoretical point of view? Something like "how can bash do that"... you're not interested in the sequence i.e. "which process is launched first"? (Because that is answered I think in the link I posted above).

Comment: I have edited my question to specify that i mean the system calls needed.

Comment: @ArturFH thank you for the answer but it is still not clear for me :( Why there is need for the dup() syscall ?

Comment: Does this help? https://brandonwamboldt.ca/how-linux-pipes-work-under-the-hood-1518/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good explanation: https://brandonwamboldt.ca/how-linux-pipes-work-under-the-hood-1518/

tl;dr:

1. the main process (e.g. bash) creates a pipe using the `pipe()` syscall, which returns two file descriptors stored in `int pipefd[2]`.
2. Then it (bash) `fork()`s and creates the two child processes for each program.
3. In each child process the standard input or output file descriptor (of the pipe)  modified with `dup2(pipefd[READ-or-WRITE],stdinorout)`.
4. Finally, the desired program (`p1` or `p2`) is executed in the child process with reading from (or writing to) the pipe.